# Asp Core 3.1 , Cors Not works for some api method

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, cors

I have disabled cors for my web api using this code in asp core 3.1 :

```cs
app.UseCors(x => x
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin
    .AllowCredentials()); // allow credentials
```

I call my api methods by angular 9, the problem is that when I call some methods I face to Cors error like this :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://porsapp-api.ketabist.ir/api/v1/exam/get_user_next_exams' from origin 'https://porsapp-panel.ketabist.ir' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have two api methods that are written same as each other in the same controller :

```cs
[HttpGet("get_user_previous_exams")]
[ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(UserPreviousExamsResponse))]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserPreviousExams(int page_num, int page_size, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var mobile = User.TryGetUsername();
    var userId = User.GetUserId();

    if (page_num == 0)
    {
        page_num = 1;
    }

    if (page_size == 0)
    {
        page_size = 20;
    }

    var exams = await _examStudentsService.GetPreviousStudentExams(userId, mobile, page_num, page_size);
    if (exams == null || exams.CountAll == 0)
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    var res = exams.Items.Select(x => _responseMapper.ToUserPreviousExamResponse(x));

    return Ok(new UserPreviousExamsResponse
    {
        items = res.ToList(),
        count_all = exams.CountAll,
    });
}
```

Calling above code is Ok and returns my result but the following method returns Cors error !

```cs
[HttpGet("get_user_next_exams")]
[ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(List<UserNextExamResponse>))]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserNextExams(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        var mobile = User.TryGetUsername();
        var userId = User.GetUserId();

        var exams = await _examStudentsService.GetFutureStudentExams(userId, mobile);
        if (exams == null || exams.Count == 0)
        {
            return Ok(new List<UserNextExamResponse>());
        }

        var res = exams.Select(x => _responseMapper.ToUserNextExamResponse(x, _settingsReader));
        return Ok(res.ToList());
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex);
    }

}
```

Please help me fix this error

Comment: Check to make sure you're not getting an exception, set a breakpoint on your backend and see if it gets hit. IIS error pages don't have CORS headers. It's not saying it doesn't match, it's saying the header isn't there. Also check the network tab and make sure your get parameters are present, and put [FromQuery] on them.

Comment: Where you put the cors configuration in start up?You need to put it between `app.UseRouting();` and `app.UseAuthorization();`.

Answer (score 0):

1.Try to make sure your configuration of cors is in the right place:

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors(x => x
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin
    .AllowCredentials());
app.UseAuthorization();
```

2.If you are hosting your project in IIS,you need to set Response Headers `Allow-Access-Control-Origin *` in IIS.